# Сохранение исключения для последующего выбрасывания

Tags: c++, исключения

Обычно когда ловится исключение оно либо сразу обрабатывается, либо бросается дальше. А вот можно ли делать так: сохранить указатель на объект исключения, выйти из блока `catch`, сделать ещё что-то, а потом бросить сохранённое исключение?

Другими словами, законен ли такой (работающий) код:

```
std::exception* SavedException = nullptr;
while(ThereIsSomethingToDo())
{
    try {
        DoSomething(); // Здесь может быть брошено исключение
    }
    catch(std::exception& e)
    {
        SavedException = &e;
            // Продолжаем делать что-то, что должно быть сделано
    }
}
    // Всё, больше делать нечего
if(SavedException) throw *SavedException;
```

Понятно, что код требует доработки для случая, когда может быть брошено больше одного исключения, но мой вопрос не об этом. Может ли к моменту выполнения `throw *SavedException` испортиться объект исключения, на который указывает `SavedException`? До каких пор указателем на этот объект можно пользоваться?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Да, ваш указатель протухает. Используйте `std::exception_ptr`. Он работает примерно как `shared_ptr` для исключений:

```
std::exception_ptr saved_exception;
while (ThereIsSomethingToDo())
{
    try
    {
        DoSomething();
    }
    catch (std::exception &e)
    {
        saved_exception = std::current_exception();
    }
}

if (saved_exception)
    std::rethrow_exception(saved_exception);
```

Answer (score 3):

Вот так можно, если я верно понимаю, что вы хотите...

```
catch(std::exception& e)
{
    // Продолжаем делать что-то, что должно быть сделано

    throw;  // Просто повторить исключение, которое обрабатываем, и отправить дальше
}
```

Если же вы хотите сгенерировать исключение после того, как закончите весь цикл — это чревато недоразумениями. Например, у вас было несколько исключений. Почему "регенерировать" именно последнее?

**Update** к вопросу, все ли будет в порядке...

Нет, не будет, сохранения нет. Это локальная переменная, которая уничтожается после обработки, т.е. вы получаете типичное UB.

Посмотрите сами на [простой тестовый код](https://ideone.com/grWrrs):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

class Ex
{
public:
    Ex(){ cout << "ctor\n"; }
    Ex(const Ex&){ cout << "cctor\n"; }
    ~Ex() { cout << "dtor\n"; }
};


int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        try
        {
            throw Ex();
        }
        catch(Ex&e)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Видите? Исключения по окончании обработки просто нет...

Comment: Нет, это совсем не то. Я хочу, чтобы цикл продолжал крутиться, пока вся работа не будет сделана, и лишь потом перебросить исключение.

Comment: Плохая идея. Какое именно из, скажем, 20 исключений вы хотите сгенерировать? А если они еще и разные производные от `exception`? Нет, лучше уж просто выставьте флаг, а потом по нему сгенерируйте новое исключение, говорящее о том, что были исключения. Хотя идеологически это неверно: у вас уже обработаны все исключения, и исключительной ситуации, как таковой, нет.

Comment: Это уже другой вопрос, с ним можно разобраться. В конце концов, я могу запретить DoSomething выбрасывать новые исключения, если одно уже есть. Меня волнует, не перезапишется ли в один прекрасный момент память, где лежит объект исключения, пока цикл будет крутится. Пока всё хорошо, но я не знаю, навсегда ли это

Comment: См. обновленный ответ.